# Check if mobile or wearable

Tags: android, wear-os

My Android app (with Wearable support) consists of three libraries: mobile (the mobile part), wear (the wearable part) and common (a common library that both mobile and wear depend on).

In some code of the common library I need to find out if it is executed on the mobile or the wearable. What would be a nice way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

There may be a straightforward, official way that someone else will propose, but here are a couple of easy DIY techniques:

1. Check for the existence of a package that's on every Wear device (but only Wear devices), like `com.google.android.apps.wearable.settings`. Potentially fragile if a Wear device (or update) arrives without this package.
2. Define resources in your own modules that are different on wearable vs. handheld. Then you can just check that resource anywhere in your code to determine which device it's running on.

Answer (score 0):

This is what I use.

```
public static boolean isWatch(Context context){
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT_WATCH) {
        return false;
    }else{
        return context.getPackageManager().hasSystemFeature(PackageManager.FEATURE_WATCH);
    }
}
```